# How can I fix my asyncio server from returning [Win 10022]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

I've been writing code for an asyncio server on my raspberry pi 4. When I was coding the Client, and did a test run with my Server class, it returns:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\####\Documents\rpiswr\client.py", line 23, in <module>
    asyncio.run(client_run())
  File "C:\Users\####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\####\Documents\rpiswr\client.py", line 18, in client_run
    await client.connect(("192.168.0.11", 56500))
  File "C:\Users\####\Documents\rpiswr\aserver\__init__.py", line 11, in connect
    print(f"Connecting as {self.s.getsockname()}")
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

I've looked up the error, and there is no substantial result. That's why I'm asking this. I'll list down my code below:

**init**.py(in directory aserver):

```py
import asyncio, socket

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def connect(self, addr):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.setblocking(False)

        print(f"Connecting as {self.s.getsockname()}")

        self.s.connect(addr)

    async def recv(self,buf_size):
        data = buf_size
        print(f"Recieved {data.decode()} in byte data")

    async def close_conn(self):
        print(f"Closed connection with server")

        self.s.close()

    async def send_bytes(self, data:bytes):
        self.s.sendall(data)

        print(f"Sent {data.decode()} in byte format")

class Server:
    """Implement handle function or decorate a function with @Server.handler(<Server>)"""

    def __init__(self, addr):
        self.addr = addr

    async def start_server(self, handler_method):
        self.server = await asyncio.start_server(handler_method, self.addr[0], self.addr[1])

        self.addr = self.server.sockets[0].getsockname()
        print(f"Serving on {self.addr}")

        async with self.server:
            await self.server.serve_forever()
```

client.py(problems occur here):

```py
from aserver import Client
import asyncio

client = Client()

async def client_run():
    await client.connect(("192.168.0.11", 56500))
    await client.send_bytes(b'Hi Echo Server!')
    await client.recv(1024)
    await client.close_conn()

asyncio.run(client_run())
```

server.py(runs perfectly well):

```py
import aserver as srv
from aserver import Server
import asyncio

server = srv.Server(["192.168.0.11", 56500])

async def echo_server(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(1024)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Recieved {message} from addr")

    print(f"Echoing {message} back")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print(f"Closing connection with {addr}")
    writer.close()

asyncio.run(server.start_server(echo_server))
```

Why is this error occurring? How do I fix this? Any answer will be appreciated. I would love if you could  fix my code where you see the problem.

Edit:

Answered by @user4815162342, but thanks everyone else who contributed!

Comment: Your client code is still wrong in that it uses blocking code inside `async def`, which can and will block the whole event loop.

Comment: @user4815162342 Sorry, but I don't really get how to stop blocking. Any chance I could get an example on how to stop blocking the event loop?

Comment: As I told you in the previous question, you can use `asyncio.open_connection` instead of raw sockets. With blocking sockets, you will get code that just looks async, but doesn't use async calls under the hood and therefore gets no benefits from asyncio.